# Does the following sentence follow complex transitive verb?

Tags: sentence-meaning, verbs, lexical-verbs

This so-called music makes me mad.

Comment: In 1. "makes" is a complex-transitive verb with "mad" as PC. The PPs in the others are complements but not predicatives, so the verbs concerned are not complex-transitives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 1. "makes" is a complex-transitive verb with "mad" as a Predicative Complement. The Prepositional Phrases in the others are complements but not predicatives, so the verbs concerned are not complex-transitives (Bill)

Answer (score 0):

The clause in question is the pattern PCR + DO    +    Object-related    PC:    complex    transitive.

So the verb phrase is a complex transitive verb.

[np+subject This so-called [n+head]music] [vp [v makes] [DO me[Complement]mad].

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).